# Best way to use inheritance in EF Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I'm trying to build a simple chat application.

I have a class User which implements IdentityUser:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a Receiver and a Sender which inherent from User:

```
public class Receiver : User
{

}
```

and

```
public class Sender : User
{

}
```

Finally I have a class Message:
A message has 1 Sender and 1 Receiver.

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sender Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual Receiver Receiver { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } 
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

These are my DbSets:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sender> Senders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
```

This is my OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Receiver)
            .WithMany(r => r.Messages)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ReceiverId);

        builder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Sender)
            .WithMany(s => s.Messages)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.SenderId);
    }
```

So my question is... Is there a better way of implementing these classes? Is there any way I could only use the User class instead of the Receiver and Sender class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinionated question, but I would add a linker table `Conversation` between `Users`.

The `Conversation` can contain all the `Messages` and the `Message` can have a link to whichever user posted it.

So the `User` can't have any `Messages` without a `Conversation`

```
public class User {
   public string Id {get;set;}
}

public class Conversation {
   public string SenderId {get;set;}
   public string RecieverId {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Message> Messages {get;set;}
}

public class Message {
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string UserId {get;set;}
   //...
}
```

Comment: The class conversation should have both user objects. Something like this:
```public class Conversation {
   public User Sender {get;set;}
   public string Reciever {get;set;}
   public string SenderId {get;set;}
   public string RecieverId {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Message> Messages {get;set;}
}```
This wil cause a many to many relation. I thought of your solution but did not implement it because of this.